# Hybrid iOS / PHP app. Pull in username as PHP variable for use as Pusher interest in Swift Code

Tags: php, ios, swift, pusher, hybrid

I am new to coding in Swift and or objective C, I only have experience in HTML / PHP and I am trying to build a Hybrid app. I used a tutorial to build a very simple webview app. The app is for family use only, it is a bespoke chat script with additional features specific to our use case. The app works just fine as it is predominantly written in PHP, but I am running into 2 issues. My App Delegate and View Controller scripts are included below.

The first is that when the app is in the foreground, perhaps I am typing a message to the family, if a notification is received during this time, perhaps someone uploads an image at the same time as I am about to post my message, then on receipt of the notification, the app refreshes, or the viewcontroller reloads, if that is the correct term? I then lose what I was typing. Is there a way to prevent a refresh on receiving a notification whilst the app is in the foreground, or better still, prevent a refresh if the keyboard is open, therefore I must be entering a message?

Secondly, I am using Pusher Beams for my notifications and this system works by subscribing to interests, as you will see by the code, I am subscribed to my username and to 'group'. I therefore have to side load each version of the app to my users, individually, first changing to their specific username. Ideally, in order to upload the app to the App Store and make it work for everyone without manually tweaking the interests and to allow regular updates, I need the Swift script to pull the username in automatically, which is a php variable '$user', from the PHP loaded script loaded in the webview and assign this to the list of interests. I do not have the first idea how to achieve this. I have read that it is possible, but beyond my capabilities.

I wondered if any of you clever people would be able to either rewrite my scripts, or perhaps advise me on how to achieve my goal?

Thank you!

```
 //
    //  ViewController.swift
    //  snipe
    //

    import UIKit
    import WebKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

        var webView: WKWebView!

        override func loadView() {
            webView = WKWebView()
            webView.navigationDelegate = self
            view = webView
        }
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()


            // 1
            let url = URL(string: "http://exampleURL.com")!
            webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))

            //2
            let refresh = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .refresh, target: webView, action: #selector(webView.reload))
            toolbarItems = [refresh]
            navigationController?.isToolbarHidden = false
        }







        func webView(_webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
            title = webView.title

        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }


    }


    //
    //  AppDelegate.swift
    //  snipe
    //

    import UIKit

    import PushNotifications

    @UIApplicationMain
    class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

        var window: UIWindow?

        let pushNotifications = PushNotifications.shared

        func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
            self.pushNotifications.start(instanceId: "##########################################")
            self.pushNotifications.registerForRemoteNotifications()
            try? self.pushNotifications.setSubscriptions(interests: ["group", "snipe"])
            return true
        }

        func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
            // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
            // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
        }

        func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
            // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
            // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
        }

        func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
            // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
        }

        func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
            // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.



            UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0


        }

        func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
            // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
        }







        func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
            self.pushNotifications.registerDeviceToken(deviceToken)
        }

        func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
            self.pushNotifications.handleNotification(userInfo: userInfo)

            self.window?.rootViewController = nil
            let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let vc = storyBoard.instantiateInitialViewController()
            self.window?.rootViewController = vc

            UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0

        }




    }
```

Comment: You lose your typed message because you not reload messenger, you create new view controller on didReceiveRemoteNotification

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. As I am a complete Swift novice, could you please advise on which pieces of code, which I put together by simply following a tutorial, would need to be changed in order to prevent the reload on receipt of a notification when in foreground? Many thanks!